# Segueing to a different view after loading AdMobs interstitial ad

Tags: swift, admob, segue, interstitial

I'm trying to load an interstitial ad between segueing from 1 ViewController to another. When pressing the button that introduces the segue the interstitial ad shows up. The user can now hit the X button to make it disappear but unfortunately the user returns back to the screen that was initially there before the interstitial ad appeared. What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBAction func segueHome(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.interstitial.isReady {
        if (advertisement == true){
            print("true");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("presentHome", sender: self);
            });
        }
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("presentHome", sender: self);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to do something very similar, where there is an interstitial before a segue. I can't get both of them to fire in succession though. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Nope. Sorry no solution found yet.

Comment: Let's try solving this together! Are you getting this error in the log? Warning: Attempt to present ###### whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I figured this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469656/swift-xcode-admob-interstitial-during-dismissviewcontroller/38490414